# XML Transformation and SQL Performance

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have a scenario where I got 100+ procedures written, these are doing the following tasks

1. loading XML files
2. Manipulating with data that come from XML
3. store or update data into the tables

All of those procedures contains temporary tables. Which affect the SQL Server performance.Currently all of procedures are running by scheduled jobs. And that makes server busy. I'm searching for some optimized way to perform transformation so that it won't effect the SQL performance. I don't have a much experience to do it. is there any clue how to make it happen.

here is the code how I'm getting XML data

```
CREATE TABLE #XMLWithOpenXML([Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, [XMLData] [xml] NULL)
CREATE TABLE #AllFiles  (Id INT IDENTITY, Subdirectory NVARCHAR(100), Depth INT, [File] INT)
CREATE TABLE #RowDetail (colone INT, ColTwo NVARCHAR(50), ColThree NVARCHAR(50), )

INSERT INTO #AllFiles 
EXEC xp_dirtree 'C:\XmlFiles',1,1
DELETE FROM #AllFiles  WHERE [file] = 0
DECLARE @Count AS INT, @FileName AS NVARCHAR(100), @Index AS INT, @Query AS NVARCHAR(4000)
SET @Index = 1
SELECT @Count = COUNT(*) FROM #AllFiles 
WHILE(@Index <= @Count)
BEGIN
    SELECT @FileName = Subdirectory FROM #AllFiles  WHERE Id = @Index
    SET @Query = 
    'INSERT INTO #XMLWithOpenXML (XMLData)
    SELECT CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn) AS BulkColumn 
    FROM OPENROWSET(BULK ''C:\XmlFiles\' + @FileName + ''', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x;'
    EXEC(@Query)
    SET @Index = @Index + 1
END

DECLARE @XML AS XML, @hDoc AS INT
SET @Index = 1
SELECT @Count = COUNT(*) FROM #XMLWithOpenXML 
WHILE(@Index <= @Count)
BEGIN
    SET @XML = NULL
    SELECT @XML = XMLData FROM #XMLWithOpenXML  WHERE Id = @Index
    EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XML

    INSERT INTO #RowDetail
    SELECT  x.colone,
            x.ColTwo,
            x.ColThree
    FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, '/root/dir/subdir')
    WITH 
    (   
        colone INT '../@Id',
        ColTwo NVARCHAR(50) '@name',
        ColThree NVARCHAR(50) '@value'
    ) AS x

    IF(@hDoc IS NOT NULL)
        EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc

    SET @Index = @Index + 1
END
```

I'm tackling with different XML formats. Each format contains many XML files. I have to load all of those accordingly along with optimized way.

Comment: "Which may effect [affect] the SQL Server performance" - why do you suspect that?

Comment: I'm doing SQL monitoring as well. ofcourse when it goes for bulk of xml files to Transform by Openrow (SQL) it took time and resources as well. and there are other procedures as well which actually doing same thing but stores differently. thats taking up time and resources of SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

How are you loading the XML into your SPs? Your comment points to `OPENROW`? Please show your actual code!

The fastest way - as far as I know - was do load the XML into a typed variable:

```
DECLARE @yourXML AS XML=
(
SELECT CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn,2) AS BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'PathToFile.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x
);
SELECT @yourXML;
```

How many XMLs are there and of which size?. You might load them in a table, each in one row.

Are these XMLs all of the same structure or not? If yes you might speed this up using a Schema.

How do you shred them (show your code!)? The fastest approach should be using the XML methods like `.nodes()`, `.value()`, `.query()` and `.exist()`. In very rare scenarios the (outdated!!!) `FROM OPENXML` might be worth a try...

What are you doing with the XMLs? Read the data and fill them into your tables? Do you change the XML (`.modify()`)? Do you write it back to the filesystem?

You write about "temporary tables"... Where and why do you need them? I most cases temp tables are a side effect of bad thinking (row based instead of set based approaches).

Without your actual code it's hard to point you anywhere. Show your code :-)

Comment: I have dispathed the queries. this is how data is loading from XML and stores into the temporary tables. furthur more there are joins with those temporary tables to store values into the tables.

Comment: @WaqasAhmad OK, thx for the full code, much clearer now... You are using `FOR OPENXML` which is outdated. There are very rare scenarios where this still might be a good approach, but not in the way you handle this here... As I see you are taking always three values (colOne, colTwo and colThree). Please provide one or two sample XML and how you want the data to be extracted. This is - for sure - much easier to solve...

Comment: I have different XML's, I have to parse every XML and fetch required columns that has to be store in a temporary table. Problem is there when I load buld of XML's then it takes time then second use of temporary tables, that also a resource consumption activity. as I have to run more than 100 procedures.

Comment: @WaqasAhmad, Hmmm... Loading **many and big** files will take a while, Running XML shredding on all of them, all **with differing structure and differin target tables** sounds like a pain in the neck... For sure your approach with `FROM OPENXML`  is much slower than it was to get the values directly out of the XML already existing in your `#XMLWithOpenXML` via XPath/XQuery. I'd need real data examples and expected output to give you an example...